# Spring Data JDBC: Can I create my UUID PKs on the client side, and not on the server?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

Client side PK creation is pretty common, especially when using UUIDs as keys. Unfortunately I can't see where this is supported in Spring Data JDBC. I get these errors instead:

```
Failed to execute DbAction.UpdateRoot(entity=my.agg.root.ClassName@28f2d8e6)
```

Grepping the Spring Data JDBC source for `DbAction.UpdateRoot`, I found [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/53bed2613b1f9533c00c59ba490491ce6a058eb2/spring-data-relational/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/relational/core/conversion/WritingContext.java#L91) in `o.s.d.relational.core.Conversion.WritingContext`:

```
    List<DbAction<?>> save() {

        List<DbAction<?>> actions = new ArrayList<>();
        if (isNew(root)) {

            actions.add(setRootAction(new DbAction.InsertRoot<>(entity)));
            actions.addAll(insertReferenced());
        } else {

            actions.add(setRootAction(new DbAction.UpdateRoot<>(entity)));
            actions.addAll(deleteReferenced());
            actions.addAll(insertReferenced());
        }

        return actions;
    }
```

I didn't dig into `isNew()`, but if it is a simple `null` check of my object's `@Id` field, then maybe the repo will always flag my object as existing, and try and `UPDATE` rather than an `INSERT`, if my `@Id` is set. In which case I'm out of luck.

Should I just write my own `@Query` method with an `INSERT` instead, upon object creation?

Thanks!